# Storing word frequencies from a text file in a map object

Tags: java, treemap

I am making the following class which creates a WordDistribution object. This object is essentially a TreeMap which is formatted to contain every word in a text file (all words are all converted to lowercase) as well as the frequency of that word in the text. The keys are the words and the values are the frequencies. I have already tried to test the constructor but the object keeps returning empty when I print it. I was wondering whether the constructor functions correctly and creates the correct object given a proper file input.

```
public class WordDistribution {

// fields
   private static TreeMap<String, Integer> wordDistribution;

// constructors
   public WordDistribution(File f) throws FileNotFoundException{

   Scanner file = new Scanner(f);
   wordDistribution = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
   while (file.hasNext()) {
       String word = file.next().toLowerCase();
       if(!wordDistribution.containsKey(word)){
           wordDistribution.put(word, 1);
       }else{
           int count = wordDistribution.get(word);
           wordDistribution.put(word, count + 1);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: *"when I print it"* Your entire question centers around the "print" and you don't include that code in the question, so how are we to know what you do wrong there? --- Anyway, using a constructor to initialize a static field is wrong. Either make the field non-static, or change the constructor to a static method.

Comment: My only advice in addition to the answer would be to review the default delimiters for `Scanner`.  Normally these are set to white space; that means that a word like "stop" and the same word at the end of a sentence "stop." will be counted as different words.  Normally that's undesired in an inverted index like this, so consider changing the default to something better for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Your `File` is probably not where you think it is, so log that. Next, your `wordDistribution` should not be `static` (else you reset it with every constructor call). You should also close your `Scanner` (or else you, potentially, leak file handles), here I used a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Finally, I would prefer a more generalized put call with `count` and prefer the interface `Map` (and diamond operator `<>`).

```
public class WordDistribution {
    // fields
    private Map<String, Integer> wordDistribution = new TreeMap<>();

    // constructors
    public WordDistribution(File f) throws IOException {
        System.out.printf("Reading: %s%n", f.getCanonicalPath());
        if (!f.canRead()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(String.format("File %s can not be read",
                    f.getCanonicalPath()));
        }

        try (Scanner file = new Scanner(f)) {
            while (file.hasNext()) {
                String word = file.next().toLowerCase();
                int count = 0;
                if (wordDistribution.containsKey(word)) {
                    count = wordDistribution.get(word);
                }
                wordDistribution.put(word, count + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Disagree with logging file not found exception.  This is exactly the sort of exception that *should* be thrown.  If the file isn't found, it's the caller's fault (the caller supplies the file name), so it's the caller's responsibility to decide how to deal with the exception.  (Maybe instead of logging, display an error dialog; but low level methods like this should never swallow exceptions, even with the excuse that a log entry was made.)